# Unzip a 7z file in google colab?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, project, kaggle, google-colaboratory

I am trying to write a CNN on Kaggle’s Amazon from Space dataset. I can’t spend money now. So, I want to use Google colab. I have successfully downloaded the dataset using kaggle cli tool. However, I am not able to extract the data. Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
!7z e train-jpg.tar.7z
```

See if you get the tar file, then `tar -xvf`

Also check that `train-jpg.tar.7z` is in the current directory too.