# while unzipping this file it give me this error : bad zip-file file is not a zip file

Tags: python, unzip

I want to extract zip-file. file name is `test.zip.001`.
I am trying to unzip this file but it gives me this error:

> bad ZipFile: File is not a zip file

This is my code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
file_name="test.zip.004"
with ZipFile(file_name,'r') as zip:
    zip.extractall()
    print("Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. Are you sure that `test.zip.004` is actually a valid zip file?

If you are running on Linux, or have access to the commandline `unzip` command, try testing that the file is valid.

```
# Check that it is valid
$ unzip -t test.zip.004
Archive:  test.zip.004
    testing: abc                      OK
No errors detected in compressed data of test.zip.004.

# Corrupt the zip file
$ echo xxx >test.zip.004

# unzip spots the corruption
$ unzip -t test.zip.004
Archive:  test.zip.004
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of test.zip.004 or
        test.zip.004.zip, and cannot find test.zip.004.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: i am using window and working on Diabetic retinopathy detection. the dataset avialable in kaggle is in this form test.zip.001 now i don't know whether it is a zip file or not?

Comment: Is the file available on the web somewhere we can access it?

Comment: this is my code https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dM8vgeI-SBFi_LcrU5Wbmep0JHxcV6Fl#                                                                         and link for data is :https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection/data

Comment: I see in the kaggle linke it says "Due to the extremely large size of this dataset, we have separated the files into multi-part archives. We recommend using 7zip or keka to extract".  You need to combine the 7 parts of test.zip files before you can read it. Try 7zip.

Comment: sir do you have any code for unziping this file in google colab using 7zip

Comment: Never heardrd of colab, but a quick search found these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955814/unzip-a-7z-file-in-google-collab and https://forums.fast.ai/t/unzipping-tar-7z-files-in-google-collab-notebook/14857